# hide searchController searchBar in navigationBar programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

I am using a searchController in the navigationBar to display a searchBar and it works very well.  The problem is when I pop my viewController to another viewController without a searchBar in the navigationBar it momentarily covers a part of the viewThat is being popped to while the navigationBar resizes.

Is there anyway to programmatically hide  the searchBar prior to removing the view without manually adjusting the frame size?

Comment: What if in `viewWillDisappear`, you fade the search bar out and remove it from the nav bar?

Comment: I tried to do that but removing it from the navBar self.navigationItem.searchController = nil does not change the size of the navigationBar in time

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I'm having the same problem right now…

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm stuck trying to do the same thing.